# Can scrapy download pdf completely

Tags: python, pdf, stream, scrapy

I want to download many pdf files from the pdf web links crawled by scrapy spiders, but when I use `scrapy.Request(pdf_url)` in filespipeline to crawl the pdf web, eventually it downloaded incomplete pdf files. all the pdf files was 1 KB Other than the first few files( which are complete). I had to use `requests.get(pdf_url, stream=True)` to download all the pdf files completely, but it is too slow. I want to know if scrapy filespipelines has similar method like this ?

Comment: Is it possible that the server is preventing many concurrent downloads from the same IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if `scrapy` can do that job. You can use `wget` library to download it.

```
import wget
pdf_url = "url_of_the_pdf.pdf"
wget.download(pdf_url)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I just want to make consistent with scrapy framework, and I am not sure whether scrapy have the same stream method to download pdf file. I appreciate scrapy 's speed at crawling websites, so it is hard for me to discard it.